# XSLT transformation with output required from recursive nodes

Tags: xslt, recursion

I am new to XSLT, having issue writing a transformation for below sample xml.

Sample XML

```
<exports>
    <job>Job1</job>
    <date>Wed Sep 27 13:19:29 CDT 2017</date>
    <targets>
        <target server-name="">
            <templates>
                <template />
                <template />
            </templates>
            <components>
                <component>test2server</component>
                <component>test4server</component>
            </components>
        </target>
    </targets>
    <auditrun template="RHEL">
        <objects-audited />
        <Changed-targets>
            <target>test2server</target>
            <target>test4server</target>
        </Changed-targets>
        <unchanged-targets />
        <changed-audit-items>
            <node1>"file"</node1>
            <node2>"filename1"</node2>
            <node3>"filename1"</node3>
            <target>"test2server"</target>
            <node5>"lastnight"</node5>
        </changed-audit-items>
        <changed-audit-items>
            <node1>"registryval"</node1>
            <node2>"filename2"</node2>
            <node3>"filename2"</node3>
            <target>"test4server"</target>
            <node5>"morning"</node5>
        </changed-audit-items>
    </auditrun>
</exports>
```

**Desired Output**

```
Changed Audit Items 1
node 1 - file
node 2 - filename1
node 3 - filename1
target - test2server
node 5 - lastnight

Changed Audit items 2
node 1 - registryval
node 2 - filename2
node 3 - filename2
target - test4server
node 5 - morning
```

My transformation - i am using the below for loop and have added text & values to print the output but failed to get the desired output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="text" indent="no" />

    <xsl:template match="/exports">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="auditrun" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="auditrun/changed-audit-items">
        <xsl:for-each select="exports/auditrun/changed-audit-items/node3">
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no"> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"> Changed Targets: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="//changed-audit-items/target/text()" disable-output-escaping="no" />
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:variable select="1" name="counter" />
        <xsl:variable select="count(//changed-audit-items/node3)" name="CountAuditItems" />
        <Audit>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(//Changed-targets/target)" disable-output-escaping="no" />
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no"> Total number of Changed Server Items: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(//changed-audit-items/node3)" disable-output-escaping="no" />
        </Audit>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no"> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">node1 </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="//changed-audit-items/node1/text()" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no"> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">node3: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="//changed-audit-items/node3/text()" disable-output-escaping="no" />
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no"> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">Node2: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="//changed-audit-items/node2/text()" disable-output-escaping="no" />
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no"> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">node4</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="//changed-audit-items/node4/text()" disable-output-escaping="no" />
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no"> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would like to request the experts for their guidance.

Regards,
R

Comment: You are not using "the below loop", or if you are, then you are not using XSLT.

Comment: Here is the transformation which I had written.

Answer (score 0):

The desired output can be achieved by using nested `<xsl:for-each>` loops. The outer for looping the `<changed-audit-items>` nodes to add the title `Changed Audit Items` and the inner for looping all the child nodes of `<changed-audit-items>`. The inner loop will print the node name and its value in the output.

Below is the XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:variable name="groupTitle" select="'Changed Audit Items '" />
    <xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#10;'" />
    <xsl:variable name="hyphenSeparator" select="' - '" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- loop for all <changed-audit-items> nodes -->
        <xsl:for-each select="//changed-audit-items">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($groupTitle, position())" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
            <!-- loop for all child nodes of <changed-audit-items> -->
            <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                <xsl:value-of select="local-name(.)" />
                <xsl:value-of select="$hyphenSeparator" />
                <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="no"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
Changed Audit Items 1
node1 - "file"
node2 - "filename1"
node3 - "filename1"
target - "test2server"
node5 - "lastnight"

Changed Audit Items 2
node1 - "registryval"
node2 - "filename2"
node3 - "filename2"
target - "test4server"
node5 - "morning"
```

Comment: Thank you Aniket. I will give this a try and see how it goes.